# accessing NPM-compiled-javascript functions from console

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, laravel-8

I'm writing an application with Laravel and using NPM to compile my JavaScript codes and I want some of my functions to be accessible from my document and actually I'm trying to call a function in `onclick` attribute of an i-tag. I've tried `npm run watch-poll`, `module.exports` and they didn't work.

is it possible to access those functions from document or not or should I write those functions that I want to be accessible in the document it self?

Comment: Please can you show what the functions are and where you've defined them.

Comment: It depends on how you define your function. If you want to access it from your browser console then you could set it as a property on the `window` object. Then you could run it by entering `window.yourFunction()` in the browser console.

Comment: thank you a lot, that does the job I want exactly. @EmielZuurbier

Comment: There are other ways to attach click event handlers to document elements. You can for example use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) within your .js file that gets transpiled by NPM so you don't need to add functions to your `window` object.

Comment: sure that is possible, I appreciate that @apokryfos